# Store nickname and psswrd in a DBMS in efficient way

Tags: database-design

Which of the 2 following option would you choose, and why?

OPTION 1:

```
Customer -> CustomerID_PK, DateOfBirth, Address, Username, Password
```

OPTION 2:

```
Customer -> CustomerID_PK, DateOfBirth, Address
CustomerInfos -> CustomerID_PK, Username, Password
```

You have no idea if it is important for managers to store all the previous usernames and passwords of each customer. You just know that each customer can change his password and his nickname whenever he wants. Regardless of the security aspect, which approach would you follow?

Comment: "You have no idea" You should ask.

Answer (score 2):

Well-designed databases are reasonably good models of the physical world. So, when deciding questions like yours, think about what happens in the world.

Your [entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) here is the Customer. What attributes should a Customer have? What attributes inherently belong to each Customer? Customers are natural persons, so they each have a unique date of birth.  In your system each Customer has exactly one Username and Password.  So these are the obvious attributes.

- Username
- Password
- DateOfBirth

You may also decide that your Customer can have exactly one address. Or, maybe a customer can have multiple addresses according to your business rules (home, office?)  If you choose the "exactly one address" business rule, the Address is also an attribute of your Customer entity. If not, you have a separate entity called Address, looking something like this. (type is 'home' , 'office', etc).

```
(address_id PK, customer_id FK, type, address)
```

If you need to store previous username/password combinations for Customers, you need a separate Credential entity. Each Customer will have one or more Credentials.  So the credential table looks something like this.

```
(credential_id PK, customer_id FK, username, password, effective_date)
```

At any rate, you should -- for data-engineering clarity -- use one table to store one entity.  So, I suggest Option 1.

This is a practical suggestion. Schemas only get more tables added to them over time, so avoiding extra tables is good. Schemas containing multiple tables with the same surrogate (autoincrementing) primary keys are harder to understand and maintain, and those extra tables are unnecessary.

Exception:  you already have millions of Customers and you need to add more attributes, but you can't afford the downtime to reorganize the table and add columns.